# Why is my plot empty?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm trying to plot a PDE solution with this code:

```
sol1 = 
  DSolve[
    {D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], t] == e^-x, 
     y[0, t] == 0, y[Pi, t] == 0, y[x, 0] == sin(2x)}, 
    y[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, Infinity}]

Plot[y[x, t] /. sol1, {x, -10, 10}]
```

I'm getting an empty plot:

[image]

Please help

Comment: Syntax issue such as `Exp[]` and `Sin[]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for DSolve would be

```
DSolve[{D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], t] == E^-x, y[0, t] == 0, 
  y[Pi, t] == 0, y[x, 0] == Sin[2 x]}, y, {x, t}]
```

But DSolve can not solve it. Maybe there is no analytical solution. Use NDSolve (with t limited, not Infinity)

```
ysol = y /. 
  First@NDSolve[{D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], t] == E^-x, 
 y[0, t] == 0, y[Pi, t] == 0, y[x, 0] == Sin[2 x]}, 
 y, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 10}]

Manipulate[Plot[ysol[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}], {t, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[ysol[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All
]
```

Using MMA version **12.2.0** can solve:

```
 DSolve[{D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], t] == E^-x, y[0, t] == 0, 
y[Pi, t] == 0, y[x, 0] == Sin[2 x]}, y[x, t], {x, t}]

 (*{{y[x, t] -> 
 Sin[2 x] (Cosh[4 t] - Sinh[4 t]) + 
  Inactive[Sum][(
 2 E^(-\[Pi] - 
   t K[1]^2) ((-1)^K[1] - E^\[Pi]) (-1 + E^(t K[1]^2)) Sin[
   x K[1]])/(\[Pi] (K[1] + K[1]^3)), {K[1], 1, \[Infinity]}]}}*)
```